# Magento 2.3.3 can't resize images

Tags: magento2, image, image-resize

I have upgraded my Magento from 2.2.7 to 2.3.3. After I upgrade it, I can't run command line:

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

It always shows bug: libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using **png_read_image**

[image]

Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `convert` Linux utility if you're on Linux server/machine.
To check arguments you can check here -
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/convert.im6.1.html

In your image directory you can run the command like following ;

```
find . -iname '*.png' -execdir convert {} -interlace none {} \;
```

the above command will find files with png extension and run convert for them.

Comment: Thank you, But our file is JPG and We can't convert it.

Comment: the command would remove interlacing from your png images, I would recommend that you try this on your local/dev setup first and then do on production environment.

Comment: Thank you. I have run it but it doesn't work. http://prntscr.com/pr3mnb Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry about that, please try the updated command.

Answer (score 0):

https://prnt.sc/w8hb0e

https://prnt.sc/w8hbar

`find . -iname '*.png' -execdir convert {} -interlace none {} \;`

https://prnt.sc/w8hbst